# jdbc autocommit(false) doesnt work

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

There is something i don't understand with `java.sql.Connection.commit()`.

I am using Derby(Java DB) as database server.

when I do a **setAutoCommit(false)** , I expect my query not to work before I explicitly call the commit() method.
but in fact, it still commit even if I don't call commit().
when I call a select * on my table to print the content, I can see that the rows have been added even though i didn't explicitly commit the query.

Could someone give me some explanation please?

```
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement updateHair = null;
    PreparedStatement addMan = null;
    try {

         String updateString =
                    "update PERSONNE " +
                    "set haircolor = 'RED' where haircolor = 'SHAVE'";

         String updateStatement =
                    "insert into personne values " +
                    "(3,'MICHEL','SHAVE')";

         addMan = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
         addMan.executeUpdate();

         updateHair = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
         updateHair.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto-commit means that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is automatically committed right after it is executed. The default is for a SQL statement to be committed when it is completed, not when it is executed. A statement is completed when all of its result sets and update counts have been retrieved. In almost all cases, however, a statement is completed, and therefore committed, right after it is executed.

The way to allow two or more statements to be grouped into a transaction is to disable the auto-commit mode.

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

When the auto-commit mode is disabled, no SQL statements are committed until you call the method commit explicitly. All statements executed after the previous call to the method commit are included in the current transaction and committed together as a unit.

**-- EDIT_1**

Updates may be committed because you're closing your Connection without calling `rollback()`.

If a Connection is closed without an explicit commit or a rollback the behaviour depends on database.

> It is strongly recommended that an application explicitly commits or
>   rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the close method. If
>   the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the
>   results are implementation-defined.

[Connection.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close--)

Comment: thanks, i though Commit() was suppose to validate a query, and if i didnt use commit, then the query or transaction would have been ignored until i decide explicitely to commit(). in my code, i use a setautocommit(false), so, if i never commit(), at the end of the block, an implicit commit will be done, is this what you mean?

Comment: ok, i understood something, when i do my select * after my insert , i have the news rows added that are printed, but if i stop the program and then do a select * once again, i can see that only the commited instruction have been saved. so,there is a trick, the commit() save the result for good in the database, but why do i obtain temporary results while the program is still running?

Comment: @GregArtisi Statements executed within a transaction see the changes done in that same transaction. So if you first insert a row, then select in that same transaction, you'll see that row (but other transactions will not). If you then rollback the transaction (eg by closing the the connection, or calling `rollback()`), it is as if it has never happened.

Comment: Note that most database drivers will rollback on connection close, as far as I know, the Oracle driver is (or was) one of the few exceptions which committed instead.

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Same thing is happening with mysql driver also. On closing connection without explicit commit or rollback results in committing the things.