# Why connection still commits automatically after putting setAutoCommit(false)?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using a MySQL database.

I have a code like this :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String url = "....";
        String username = "...";
        String password = "...";
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("create table if not exists customer1\r\n" + "(\r\n"
                + "customer_name varchar(20) not null primary key,\r\n" + "customer_street varchar(20),\r\n"
                + "customer_city varchar(10)\r\n" + ")");
        // connection.commit();  
        connection.close();

    }

}
```

**Problem:** When I execute this, it creates the table and commits it automatically but it should not.

I did `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` and commented out `connection.commit()` for testing, then why it is committing ?

This question ([jdbc autocommit(false) doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357848/jdbc-autocommitfalse-doesnt-work)) didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem: When I execute this, it creates the table and commits it
>   automatically but it should not.

Right, any DDL will always be committed regardless of autocommit setting.

This behavior is not specific to MySQL, see [Autocommit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocommit).

> Most DBMS (e.g. MariaDB) force autocommit for every DDL statement,
>   even in non-autocommit mode. In this case, before each DDL statement,
>   previous DML statements in transaction are autocommitted. Each DDL
>   statement is executed in its own new autocommit transaction.

Maybe [TEMPORARY TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) might help you.

> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY
>   table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped
>   automatically when the session is closed. This means that two
>   different sessions can use the same temporary table name without
>   conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of
>   the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table
>   is dropped.)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this creation ?

Comment: @AnishB. depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can try [TEMPORARY TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html)

Comment: I wrote this `stmt.execute("create temporary table if not exists customer1\r\n" + "(\r\n"
                + "customer_name varchar(20) not null primary key,\r\n" + "customer_street varchar(20),\r\n"
                + "customer_city varchar(10)\r\n" + ")");` Still creating table.

Comment: Can you add the jdbc example with temporary table ?

Comment: @AnishB. table is created, but it's visible only in current session (connection) and will disappear when session is closed. Maybe if you explain what you're trying to achieve ..

Answer (score 1):

MySQL DDL, i.e. creating table isn't transactional

ref [transactions that cause implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html)

Answer (score 1):

Data Manipulation statements are transactional,  not Data definition statements.

so create/alter table or drop table  are still committed.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this creation by modify this code ?

Comment: In some database systems, DDL is transactional.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But mine is MySQL. I'm not able to avoid this. Is there any way to make DDL transactional in MySQL.?

Comment: @AnishB. No you cannot, but why do you event want that?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel There is a requirement like I have list of queries which contains DDL, DML and so on. If any failure happens, then everything should be reverted back including the table creation. How should I approach to prevent DDL to be happening in case of rollback ?

Comment: @AnishB. You can't. Execute the DDL first, and have a script ready to undo any DDL changes you did in case of failure. That said, having such requirements with regard to DDL is pretty odd in itself.